# I get missing dependency error when migrating code from angular 7 to 10

Tags: javascript, angular, migration

I am migrating my project from angular 7 to 10. I have done an import as `import { AgmJsMarkerClustererModule } from '@agm/js-marker-clusterer';` When I try to compile the project, I get the following error.

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "@agm/js-marker-clusterer" has missing dependencies:
- @agm/core/services/google-maps-types
```

So I tried to install the missing dependency by `npm install @agm/core/services/google-maps-types` and I end up getting another error

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "@agm\core\services\google-maps-types" as it does not contain a  
         package.json file.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-09T09_07_23_516Z-debug.log
```

I have angular cli 10.1 installed. Please help

Comment: try `npm update @agm/core`

Comment: Doesn't change anything, was already using latest version

Comment: Try this specific version once `npm install @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.7`. For more information, Kindly refer this [link](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1729)

Comment: try delete the package `js-marker-clusterer` in `node-modules` folder and run `npm i` .

Answer (score 4):

@agm/js-marker-clusterer has been replaced with @agm/markerclusterer

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for your response. This may be a helpful comment, but it is not an answer with instructions regarding how to resolve this issue. Please check out these tips to see what the community wants in terms of answers: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Comment: It might not solve the issue, but I appreciate this response so I can avoid the issue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Use v `1.1.0` for `agm` related dependencies and during install add flag `--legacy-peer-deps`.

Example:
`npm i @agm/core@1.1.0 --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
after these two library has the version changed from 3.0.0-beta to 1.1.0

```
@agm/core
@agm/snazzy-info-window
```

compiled successfully